# How to make name of an object key the value of a variable?

Tags: javascript

```
var orderName = document.getElementById("orderName").value;
var order = ["5", "6"];
var Orders: {
    orderName: order
}
JSON.Stringify(Orders); // returns {"ordername":[5,6]}
//Expected output would be {"Hamburger": [5,6]}
```

How can I make it so when i call JSON.Stringify(Orders) it returns the value of the element?

Comment: You've described what you're looking for, but could you provide a concrete, specific example of the output you'd expect from this?

Comment: maybe if you use computed properties, like this Orders: { [orderName]: order}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the square bracket property notation:

```js
var orderName = "Hamburger";
var order = ["5","6"];

var obj = { [orderName]: order }; 

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This works, not sure how I didn't realize this :p